# Indian Getting married in Europe and dependent visa complication work permit in different country

Tags: germany, marriage, dependent-visa, covid-19, finland

I currently hold a work permit in finland via my current Indian employer. And my fiance currently holds a blue card in Germany.

we had plan to get married this year in India but due to covid situation we are not able plan marriage in india.

So we plan to get married in Germany or EU. But we don't have required documents with us "maritial status certificate" to get married in Germany or in finland.

i have below question and need advice to take any steps further:

1. if we get married in EU and get marriage certificate, from where i will have to apply for dependent visa? germany or finland?
2. I am planning to end my current employment and move to Germany with her, without going back to India to take care of her.
3. another option if i get a german work contract and i have to file for German work permit i can't do it from germany? or it will be filed from India?

and as per my current my employer can call me back to India anytime so i plan to take 2 months leave if i can process the application from Germany.

what would be best in such situation  to avoid and negative points to my application.

Comment: Your item #2 is unclear. Removing the unnecessary material, I think you mean: _I plan to end my current employment and move to Germany with her, without going back to India._ Is that correct?

Comment: yes you are right,  as condition in india is bad,  will be difficult to travel back in short term.

Comment: I have edited #2 to conform. I deleted your statements about why you'll not return to India, as the reason is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: as we plan to get married in Germany,  and my fiance is not keeping well , she has monthly checkup and regular medicine in Germany, so we can't travel back to india in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you plan to move to Germany after you marry, you will need to apply to Germany for a dependent visa or residence permit, derivative of your wife's blue card status.  I suspect that you will be able to make the application in Finland.  You can approach a German consulate in Finland for more information.  In fact, the only diplomatic mission in Finland seems to be [the embassy in Helsinki](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/visa/local-contacts-world-map/country/by-county/finland/).

You can also look at the government's web pages.  A good place to start is probably [Spouses joining citizens of non-EU countries](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/living-in-germany/family-reunification/spouses-non-eu-countries/).

If instead you want to apply for an independent work permit in Germany through a sponsoring employer, you should still be able to do that in Finland provided that you can maintain lawful residence in Finland (that is, provided that you can retain your current employment while you're applying for the German visa).

Comment: thank you very much, but as we are not married, yet how can i file the spouse visa?

Comment: @AjayMahajan your plan is to get married.  Apply for the visa after you marry.